# Obtener OUTPUT de Procedimiento almacenado

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo por ejemplo este procedimiento almacenado

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.PersonaDoc
@cDocumento varchar (20)
AS
SELECT Ruta_Line 
FROM Persona
WHERE (documento= @cDocumento)
```

Que diferencia habría para consumirlo en C# utilizando ExecuteNonQuery, ExecuteScalar o ExecuteReader (dependiendo el caso los valores que desee devolver) si el procedimiento almacenado es

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.PersonaDoc
@cDocumento varchar (20)
@resultado int OUTPUT
AS
SELECT SET@resultado = nombre
FROM Persona
WHERE (documento= @cDocumento)
```

Lo que no me queda claro es la diferencia entre consumir los datos que trae directamente el procedimiento almacenado o utilizar un valor output para el mismo, supongo que en el primer caso como ventaja seria que puedo traer varios valores y con el OUTPUT uno solo, pero suponiendo que solo quiero un valor de retorno es lo mismo?

Comment: Me pasa que si el usuario o contraseña no existen me genera un error: "System.InvalidOperationException: Error de lectura porque no hay datos. en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckMetaDataIsReady()" como puede resolverse eso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diferencias:

- `ExecuteNonQuery` ejecutará el Stored Procedure y no te devolverá ningún resultado
- `ExecuteScalar` te revolverá un solo dato, con el cual podrás hacer uso del lado de tu aplicación
- `ExecuteReader` se utiliza cuando deseas obtener un conjunto de datos, es decir, múltiples filas y múltiples columnas.

Ahora, tomando como referencia el *Stored Procedure*

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.PersonaDoc @cDocumento VARCHAR(20) @resultado INT OUTPUT
AS
    SELECT @resultado = nombre
    FROM Persona
    WHERE (documento = @cDocumento)
```

Al ejecutar:

- `ExecuteNonQuery` no obtendrás resultado
- `ExecuteScalar` te revolverá `null` dado que en el `SELECT` realizas una asignación con `@resultado = nombre`, para retornar un resultado deberás agregar `SELECT @resultado` al final de tu Stored Procedure
- `ExecuteReader` de igual forma te devolverá `null`, deberás hacer lo mismo que el `ExecuteScalar` o en su caso un `SELECT * FROM Persona` (a modo de ejemplo)

## Actualización

Con el `OUTPUT` haces una referencia por valor a la variable que tienes asignada como valor de salida, en el caso de tu *Stored Procedure* podrías usar `ExecuteScalar` o bien, `OUTPUT`, ambas se pueden ajustar a la forma en que programes. Si utilizas C#, un ejemplo de código sería el siguente para obtener el valor del documento usando `Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString ))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PersonaDoc", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cDocumento", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string documentoId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@cDocumento"].Value);
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Si entiendo la diferencia entre los distintos tipos de Execute, mi dudas es mas en la parte del procedimiento almacenado, la diferencia en tratar de obtener un resultado utilizando OUTPUT o con el valor que devuelve sin utilizar OUTPUT @Flxtr