# recibir output, parametro de sql, en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedure, parametros

buena tarde. estoy programando en vb.net y siempre e trabajado con procedimientos almacenados, pero en este caso dicho pr devuelve un output (como un resultado) y no se como recibirlo para mostrarlo en un textbox... les muestro lo que tengo realizado hasta el momento.

en primer lugar tengo vb. donde guardo todos los procedimientos y los llamo para ejecutarlos:

```html
Public Function CalculaPrecio(CODPROD As String, CUENTACLIENTE As String, DTOGRAL As Decimal, DESCUENTO As Decimal, PRECIO As Decimal, LISTADEPRECIO As Integer) As OleDbDataReader
 
    Dim myReader As OleDbDataReader
 
    Try
        Dim connexio As New OleDbConnection
        Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand
        Dim campo As String
 
        connexio = New OleDbConnection(myConnectionString)
        myCommand.CommandText = ("CalculaPrecio")
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        myCommand.Connection = connexio
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODPROD", CODPROD)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUENTACLIENTE", CUENTACLIENTE)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DTOGRAL", DTOGRAL)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESCUENTO", DESCUENTO)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRECIO", PRECIO)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LISTADEPRECIO", LISTADEPRECIO)
        myCommand.Parameters("@PRECIOFINAL").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
 
        connexio.Open()
 
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
 
        Dim PRECIOFINAL As Decimal = CInt(myCommand.Parameters("@PRECIOFINAL").Value)
 
        Return myReader
    Catch exc As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & exc.Message)
        Return myReader
    End Try
 
End Function
```

luego tengo un formulario en donde primero declaro una sub para despues ejecutarlo con dichos valores que necesito pasarle al procedimiento

```html
Public Sub CalculaPrecio(CODPROD As String, CUENTACLIENTE As String, DTOGRAL As Decimal, DESCUENTO As Decimal, PRECIO As Decimal, LISTADEPRECIO As Integer)
    Dim objStreamWriter As StreamWriter
    Dim path As String
 
    Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
 
 
    Dim myReader As OleDbDataReader
    myReader = Data.CalculaPrecio(CODPROD, CUENTACLIENTE, DTOGRAL, DESCUENTO, PRECIO, LISTADEPRECIO)
 
    Me.Refresh()
    Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
 
    path = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath
End Sub
```

por ultimo en el click la ejecución del procedimiento almacenado

```html
CalculaPrecio(txtCodProd.Text, txtClienteCuenta.Text, txtDescGral.Text, txtDescuento.Text, txtPrecio.Text, txtListaPrecio.Text)
```

la cuestión es que este procedimiento tiene un valor declarado como output como salida... no se como hacer q cuando se ejecute ese pr me grabe en una caja de texto ese resultado

espero su ayuda, desde ya muchisimas gracias

Comment: Que tal @Agustin, dale una leida a esta pregunta creo que respondera todo
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47637/obtener-output-de-procedimiento-almacenado

Comment: hola @ChristianGtz, gracias por tu ayuda. pude solucionar mi duda. sin embargo tengo otro problema. me da el valor entero, sin decimales

Comment: Cuando ejecutas el sp directamente en la base te da ese resultado ?

Comment: no, hay algo q estoy haciendo mal porque la ejecucion del proceso si me da con decimales... el procedimiento al ejecutarlo en vb, en el text recibo el valor sin decimales

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@PRECIOFINAL", SqlDbType.Decimal)
myCommand.Parameters("@PRECIOFINAL").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

            connexio.Open()

            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
 PRECIOFINAL = myCommand.Parameters("@PRECIOFINAL").Value
 frmAgregaRemito.txtPrecioFinal.Text = PRECIOFINAL

Comment: PRECIOFINAL, lo tienes declarado o simplemente es un paramentro? puedes cambiarlo a double

Comment: sisi lo tengo declarado mas arriba lo tenía como dim PRECIOFINAL as decimal, lo cambie a double y me hace lo mismo, probé con cambiar el sqldbtype.decimal a .money y tambien me da entero